# Is there some way to get a specific field from one get request with Firestore(Firebase)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So here is the request to get some data from Firestore with vanilla JS.

````
const q = query(collection(db, "tasks"), where("userId", "==", "Milos"), where("archive", "==", "false"));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});```
With this request, I get a from collection tasks where userId equals "specificname", and where the archive field is equal to false. So with this request, I will get full tasks, is there some way with Firestore to get only a specific field or fields, not a full task with all fields? Is something even possible with Firestore or do I need to parse this object on the front side?
````

Comment: Are you on the client or on the server (Node.js with `firebase-admin`)?

Comment: The Firestore client-side SDKs always return full documents, and don't have a way to request a subset of the field. Some of the server-side/Admin SDKs and the REST API have the option to get some of the fields (or even no fields at all and just the IDs).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot retrieve partial responses from Firestore on the client. Every request will always return all documents to the client. This also means you cannot protect certain fields in a document.

Server-side you could try using [Query.select](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#select).

```js
let collectionRef = firestore.collection('col');
let documentRef = collectionRef.doc('doc');

return documentRef.set({x:10, y:5}).then(() => {
  return collectionRef.where('x', '>', 5).select('y').get();
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(`y is ${res.docs[0].get('y')}.`);
});
```